# How to add a tab bar to a Mac application (Swift/AppKit)

Tags: swift, cocoa, tabs, tabbed

I am creating a code editor for Mac using Xcode and Swift. I already have a toolbar (NSToolbar) but am not sure how I would achieve a tab design simmilar to Firefox's. I don't want to use NSTabView as those are more like tabbed buttons, and I am looking for a proper tab bar for Mac.

**Example of what I want to achieve**

In the below image, I have edited the tab bar from Firefox into the design of the app so you can see what I would like to accomplish.

[image]

Will I have to implement something like this from scratch, and if so - how would I go about doing it?
Thanks, dhilln.

Comment: You get Cocoa tabs like in Xcode or Finder in macOS 10.12+ for free, but you have to develop those custom (in my opinion ugly *windows-ish*) tabs yourself.

Comment: @vadian I would prefer the native tabs if possible, but I am not using an NSDocument setup - is there a way to get those without NSDocument?

I have implemented `override func newWindowForTab(_ sender: Any?)` in my MainWindowController (extension of NSWindowController) as I tried this after some quick Googling but there still is no tab bar.

Comment: I don't know please watch the WWDC video about Cocoa from 2016 when 10.12 was introduced.

Comment: All it says is this, which is what I've tried to no avail.
"Non-NSDocument can enable the plus button by implenting newWindowForTab"

Comment: @vadian Never mind, I'll try and just see if I can remake it as an NSDocument based then

Comment: you dont need to use doc. you just need a plist setting.